# How to print the variables of an array as checkbox names in a cgi-form?

Tags: perl, cgi

Is there a simple way to print check boxes in an cgi form whose names are variables of an array?

Comment: What have you tried? What problems are you having? Please show us your code.

Answer (score 2):

You have several problems.

1. If you want to pass multiple values to a single property in a hash, then you need to pass a *reference*. Your code (before you deleted it from the question during the grace period when edits are not recorded) will be interpreted as: `checkbox("-values" -> "apple", "orange" => "berry")`.
2. `checkbox` only takes one value. If you want to pass multiple, then you need to call it multiple times
3. CGI.pm's [HTML generation functions should no longer be used](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/CGI/lib/CGI.pod#HTML-Generation-functions-should-no-longer-be-used). Switch to a template system instead.

For example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use v5.10;
use strict;
use warnings;

use Template;

my @checkbox_values = qw[apple orange berry];
my $template = q[
    Example template
    [% FOR item IN checkbox_values %]
    <input type="checkbox" name="example" value="[% item | html %]">
    [%- END %]
];

print Template->new()->process(\$template, { checkbox_values => \@checkbox_values })
```

NB: Templates are better stored in separate files.