# How to sort an hash and assign a variable to the keypair from an array in perl?

Tags: arrays, perl, sorting, hash

I have an array like this

```
my @arr =('1','apple','2','orange','1','orange','3','berry','2','berry','1','berry');
my %hash;
my $var =1;
```

Now how can i sort and assign a variable to the pair?
The desired output is

```
$hash{1}{apple} =>1;
$hash{1}{orange} =>1;
$hash{1}{berry} =>1;
$hash{2}{orange} =>1;
$hash{2}{berry} =>1;
$hash{3}{berry} =>1;
```

Comment: You can't use same keys, it will overwrite. You can go with hash of array

Comment: @mkHun Yeah,I am trying to use {1}{apple} as single key and 1 as value

Answer (score 1):

You need to iterate your array and take two values out per iteration. One way to do this is with a while loop. This will consume the array, so if you want to keep it you might want to make a copy.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Printer;

my @arr = (
    '1', 'apple', '2', 'orange', '1', 'orange',
    '3', 'berry', '2', 'berry',  '1', 'berry',
);
my %hash;
my $var = 1;

while ( my $first_key = shift @arr ) {
    my $second_key = shift @arr;
    $hash{$first_key}->{$second_key} = $var;
}

p %hash;
```

This outputs

```
{
    1   {
        apple    1,
        berry    1,
        orange   1
    },
    2   {
        berry    1,
        orange   1
    },
    3   {
        berry   1
    }
}
```

An alternative is to use a C-style `for` loop. This does not change the array.

```
for (my $i = 0; $i <= $#arr; $i+=2) {
    $hash{ $arr[$i] }->{ $arr[$i + 1] } = $var;
}
```

Or you could use [List::Util's `pairs` function](https://metacpan.org/pod/List::Util#pairs) to get two out at the same time.

```
use List::Util 'pairs';

foreach my $pair ( pairs @arr ) {
   my ( $first_key, $second_key ) = @$pair;
   $hash{$first_key}->{$second_key} = $var;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's normally expected that you at least spend a few hours *trying* to write a solution yourself. We will happily help you if you've made a decent attempt of your own but have run out of ideas, but it doesn't go down well if you appear to have dumped your problem on us and are waiting for an answer to pop up while you drink a mug of coffee. You've been [told about this before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49533073/how-to-print-the-variables-of-an-array-as-checkbox-names-in-a-cgi-form#comment86077640_49533073), and only one of your post has a net positive vote. You need to work on that.

Are you certain that you really want a hash of hashes? This is very reminiscent of your previous question [How to find if the value exists in hash without using key in perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50701681/how-to-find-if-the-value-exists-in-hash-without-using-key-in-perl) where we pretty much established that it was the wrong choice.

The only non-obvious part is extracting the values from the array in pairs, I and I have used C-style `for` loop to achieve this.

I have used `Data::Dumper` only to show the resulting hash of hashes.

```perl
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

my @arr = qw/ 1 apple 2 orange 1 orange 3 berry 2 berry 1 berry /;

my %hash;

for ( my $i = 0; $i < $#arr; $i += 2 ) {
    $hash{$arr[$i]}{$arr[$i+1]} = 1;
}

use Data::Dumper;

print Dumper \%hash;
```

#### output

```
$VAR1 = {
          '2' => {
                   'berry' => 1,
                   'orange' => 1
                 },
          '3' => {
                   'berry' => 1
                 },
          '1' => {
                   'berry' => 1,
                   'orange' => 1,
                   'apple' => 1
                 }
        };
```

#### Update

Here's an example of generating the keys as I described in the comments. It's almost identical to the solution above, but the resulting hash contents are different.

```perl
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

my @arr = qw/ 1 apple 2 orange 1 orange 3 berry 2 berry 1 berry /;

my %hash;

for ( my $i = 0; $i < $#arr; $i += 2 ) {
    $hash{"@arr[$i,$i+1]"} = 1;
}

use Data::Dumper;

print Dumper \%hash;
```

#### output

```
$VAR1 = {
          '2 berry' => 1,
          '1 apple' => 1,
          '3 berry' => 1,
          '1 orange' => 1,
          '1 berry' => 1,
          '2 orange' => 1
        };
```

Comment: Well,the actual problem is i am comparing two hashes.i.e i have to find out the unique "pairs" between them and i had a problem with this duplicate key-pairs.for ex. i needed to find out that if {1}{apple} pair existed in another hash

Comment: So,i was just trying to pair up this hash and assign it to 1 and pass the other hash pair onto this

Comment: @Sherlock.H: Right. As I said, you've picked the wrong data structure. This would be a lot easier with a one-level hash with keys `1 apple`,  `2 orange`,  `1 orange`,  `3 berry`,  `2 berry`,  `1 berry`.

Comment: I am tempted to ask "what do you mean by that" however I am holding back because you might yell at me again for not doing my research

Comment: any idea how you would get that one level hash keys?

Comment: I'm not yelling, I'm advising. I've done it rather forcefully as you should be aware of these things by now. Have you read [*"The Tour"*](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [*"How do I ask a good question?"*](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)? I think you should. In the mean time, I think you should put this into practice and try to figure out how to create a hash key of `'1 apple'` etc. It's not at all hard.

Comment: Well,thank you,i have read it now.however i am unable to compare,i did create a '1apple' as hash key though

Comment: @Sherlock.H: You just need a separator to differentiate the first part of the keys from the second. I've used a space, which is inserted by default when an array slice is stringified.

Answer (score 0):

Take the values from the array two at a time (key/value), put them into a hash, then assign the variable as the value.

```
use Data::Dumper;

sub SortAndAssign {
    my ($args) = @_;

    my @arr = @{$args->{ARRAY}};
    my $var = $args->{VARIABLE};

    my %hash;

    my $i = 0;
    my $size = scalar(@arr);
    while ($i < $size) {
        # alternating key/value pairs (really a hash)
        my $key = $arr[$i++];   # e.g. 1
        my $value = $arr[$i++]; # e.g. apple
        $hash{$key}{$value} = $var; # e.g. hash->1->apple = 1
    }

    return %hash;
}

sub ShowSortAndAssign {
    my @arr =('1','apple','2','orange','1','orange','3','berry','2','berry','1','berry');
    my $var = 1;

    my %hash = SortAndAssign({
        ARRAY => \@arr,
        VARIABLE => $var,
    });

    print Dumper(\%hash);
    print "first apple is " . $hash{1}{apple};
}

sub _Main {
    ShowSortAndAssign();
}

_Main();
```

Comment: Perl will [***autovivify***](https://perlmaven.com/autovivification) array and hash elements as necessary, so `my %tempHash = %{$hash{$key} || {}}; $tempHash{$value} = $var; $hash{$key} = \%tempHash;` is generally written as `$hash{$key}{$value} = $var`.

Comment: Thanks.  I hadn't used it multi-levels deep like that.
`while ($i < $size) {
      my $key = $arr[$i++];
      my $value = $arr[$i++];
      $hash{$key}{$value} = $var;
  }
  return %hash;`

Comment: It's best not to put code in comments if you can avoid it. I was forced to because I have no question or answer to use, but you could [*edit*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50721645/how-to-sort-an-hash-and-assign-a-variable-to-the-keypair-from-an-array-in-perl/50722709) your answer to present it properly.

Comment: Yeah I didn't want to pretend I did it that way initially and make your comment look off.  I'll edit it now.